# LTSpice error with the V() function in a subcircuit

Tags: simulation, ltspice, spice, cad, model

I'm trying to do a simulation with a subcircuit, and I've narrowed down the issue to the V() function.

The simulation fails with the message 'can't find definition of model "V" '

Here is the spice library with the subckt (RXD_33_2_TYP)
(The library was from an IBIS model converted to SPICE using microcap)

[test.lib to troubleshoot issue](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FlIe8S9ztnyhNPcga0QWTs4Ul6moqJtl)

[Original iso7421.lib](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1s3S3bbHDQVaIYbA-f3lVVMhr7U4_jfR3)

[image]

Comment: Please post the entire netlist and models

Comment: Added, see original post. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the resistance value of the variable resistor to R={V(IN)*100}.

The resulting netlist line will look like:
Rdoesntwork IN OUT R={V(IN) * 100}

Comment: That works yes, thank you.

sadly this means I have to go thru a large subckt and change these manually.

Not sure why LTSpice requires this extra "R=" wile the model was provided without it.